# Building com.android.library with buddybuild.com

Tags: android, continuous-integration

I am testing [buddybuild](http://buddybuild.com) CI for my Android projects. I have an issue with building projects that are libraries. It seems that buddybuild recognizes only "com.android.application" plugin. Have you experienced such issues? Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer from buddybuild support.

> Hi there - Thanks for reaching out!
>   Unfortunately, libraries are not supported for now but this is definitely on our roadmap.

:(

Comment: 2 years later still not supported